# How to get multiple paths returned in a Python recursive graph function?

Tags: python, recursion, graph

1) Suppose A1, B1, and C1 are nodes in this graph. C1 is upstream to B1, and B1 is upstream to A1.
See this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjygD.jpg

If I call `get_path_to_most_upstream(A1,[])` then I get `[[A1, B1, C1]]`.

2) However, this doesn't work when a node has more than one parent upstream to it.
See this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AE5u.jpg

When I call `get_path_to_most_upstream(A1,[])`, I am getting an empty list `[]` but I want to get `[[A1, B1, C1],[A1,B1,C2],[A1,B2,C3],[A1,B2,C4]]`. How can I adjust this function to return that?

```
def get_path_to_most_upstream(start_key, path):
    current_top = start_key
    path = path + [current_top] #add top node to path

    parents = get_nodes_upstream_one_hop(current_top) #returns list of nodes directly above
    #parents = [B1] in first case
    #parents = [B1, B2] in second

    if not parents: #base case
        return [path]

    paths = [] 
    for parent in parents:
        if parent not in path:
            extended_paths = get_path_to_most_upstream(parent, path)
            for p in extended_paths:
                paths.append(p)
    return paths
```

Comment: Is your graph always a tree (acyclic with one and only one node that has no incoming edges)? Your terminology is sort of inverted, but basically you want every root to leaf path, it sounds like, which is basically a depth-first traversal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python (yield): all paths from leaves to root in a tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134742/python-yield-all-paths-from-leaves-to-root-in-a-tree)

Comment: Yes it will always be an acyclic tree but not binary, there can be any number of leaf nodes. I'm going to try what you listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works with small mod.

**Mods**

1. In function get_path_to_most_upstream give path default value of None

   get_path_to_most_upstream(start_key, path = None):
2. Set path to list, if path is None

   if path is None:
         path = []

**Refactored Code**

```
def get_nodes_upstream_one_hop(node):
  return [neighbor for neighbor in graph[node]]

 def get_path_to_most_upstream(start_key, path = None):
    if path is None:
      path = []
    current_top = start_key

    path = path + [current_top] #add top node to path

    parents = get_nodes_upstream_one_hop(current_top) #returns list of nodes directly above
    #parents = [B1] in first case
    #parents = [B1, B2] in second

    if not parents: #base case
        return [path]

    paths = [] 
    for parent in parents:
        if parent not in path:
            extended_paths = get_path_to_most_upstream(parent, path)
            for p in extended_paths:
                paths.append(p)
    return paths
```

**Graph Code**

[Reference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generate-graph-using-dictionary-python/)

```
from collections import defaultdict 

# function for adding edge to graph 
graph = defaultdict(list) 
def addEdge(graph,u,v): 
    graph[u].append(v) 

# definition of function 
def generate_edges(graph): 
    edges = [] 

    # for each node in graph 
    for node in graph: 

        # for each neighbour node of a single node 
        for neighbour in graph[node]: 

            # if edge exists then append 
            edges.append((node, neighbour)) 
    return edges
```

**Testing**

*Test 1*

```
graph = defaultdict(list)
addEdge(graph, 'A1', 'B1')
addEdge(graph, 'B1', 'C1')
print(get_path_to_most_upstream('A1')) # [['A1', 'B1', 'C1']]
```

*Test 2*

```
graph = defaultdict(list)
addEdge(graph, 'A1', 'B1')
addEdge(graph, 'A1', 'B2')
addEdge(graph, 'B1', 'C1')
addEdge(graph, 'B1', 'C2')
addEdge(graph, 'B2', 'C3')
addEdge(graph, 'B2', 'C4')
print(get_path_to_most_upstream('A1')) 
# [['A1', 'B1', 'C1'], 
#  ['A1', 'B1', 'C2'], 
#  ['A1', 'B2', 'C3'], 
#  ['A1', 'B2', 'C4']]
```